# Rounding off in SQL Server by 2 places after decimal and neglecting 3rd value after decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to round off a numeric value in SQL Server.

Consider this example - my value is 179.8744.

I want it to be converted to 179.88

I have tried `ROUND` function, but it only converts if 3rd value is greater than 5. Is there any other function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to round *up*, not convert. There are a lot of duplicate questions. ROUND can only round or truncate. But rounding up is no different than truncating and adding 1 to the least significant digit

Answer (score 0):

You could get creative with the [ceiling()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql) function. This function will always round up, but to the next *integer*. For `2` decimal places this can be resolved by multiplying and dividing by `100.0`.

```
-- move decimal separator up
select 179.8744 * 100.0

-- round up to next integer
select ceiling(179.8744 * 100.0);

-- move decimal separator down (complete formula)
select ceiling(179.8744 * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2985a8835eaa492dfeb132871602cb9d)

Answer (score -1):

use decimal or round like below!
[Examples decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
select cast(179.8744 as decimal(10,2))
OR
select round(179.8744,2)
```

Comment: OP stated `I want it to be converted to 179.88`

Comment: check now  Please